# After upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10 rutorrent and nginx web console stopped working

Tags: ubuntu, php, upgrade, nginx

I did upgrade from Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10 and rutorrent stopped working with nginx.

In web I see the following error:

> [19.11.2017 17:43:07] Bad response from server: (502
>   [error,getplugins]) Bad Gateway [19.11.2017 17:43:07] Bad response
>   from server: (502 [error,getuisettings]) 502 Bad Gateway

In nginx error log I have following entries

> 2017/11/17 14:54:16 [crit] 1234#1234: *2 connect() to
>   unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or
>   directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.255.109,
>   server: 192.168.255.125, request: "POST /rutorrent/php/getsettings.php
>   HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:",
>   host: "192.168.255.125", referrer:
>   "https://192.168.255.125/rutorrent/"

No errors in php log.

`/var/run/` doesn't contain any php file/entry. I installed etckeeper
and I checked if there were any changes during the upgrade process in
`/etc` and I don't see anything there.

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Is php-fpm running? Provide you php-fpm pool config please.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderMakarenko - php-fpm is up and running.

`root@ubuntu:~# service php7.0-fpm status`
`● php7.0-fpm.service`
`Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)`
`Active: inactive (dead)`

Values:

`group = www-data`
`listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock`
`listen.group = www-data`
`listen.mode = 0660`
`listen.owner = www-data`
`pm = dynamic`
`pm.max_children = 5`
`pm.max_spare_servers = 3`
`pm.min_spare_servers = 1`
`pm.start_servers = 2`
`user = www-data`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to fix the issue. @AlexanderMakarenko had great idea to check php-fpm if it is running.

What I did is removed php-fpm completely, I removed the /etc/php/7.0 config and left 7.1. I changed the /etc/nginx/conf.d/php to point to 7.1 socket.